# How to find the IP address assigned to an interface that has been removed

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows (specifically, server 2008 R2), if a network interface dies and I replace it, how can I then retrieve the IP that was assigned to the old interface?

I know Windows retains it somewhere, because if I knew what it was and assigned it to the new interface, Windows would throw a warning and inform me that IP was assigned on this system before.

Along the same lines, if I were talking about a virtual guest that was moved to a new host that did not have the virtual network configured the same, I arrive at the same issue. I need to find the old IP and assign it to the new interface.

Thanks,

[EW]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces

via regedit

Comment: Thanks! Gets me the info I need. Have not tried it on a systems with an interface missing yet though. Will update after I have. Also, works fine converted for PowerShell:   get-childitem "hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces" |get-itemproperty |fl pschildname,*ipaddress,*subnetmask,*gatewayhardware

Comment: yep powershell works fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **netsh** command to accomplish this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 dump
```

That should give you manually assigned ipv4 interface information (active, inactive, or even removed interfaces).  *Replace with ipv6 if you need ipv6 interface information.*

**Result:**

```
# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4

reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled
add route prefix=0.0.0.0/0 interface="Local Area Connection 2" nexthop=192.168.28.1 publish=Yes
add route prefix=0.0.0.0/0 interface="Local Area Connection" nexthop=10.10.10.1 publish=Yes
add address name="Local Area Connection 2" address=192.168.28.180
add address name="Local Area Connection" address=10.10.10.212
```

Comment: That's a neat feature - I didn't know netsh would list removed interfaces. Nice.